# Angular2 Check the Class of an Element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I want to access the class of an element to check if it is "collapse in" or "collapse". I want to do something like:

```
<span *ngIf=" class == 'collapse in' "> - </span>
<span *ngIf=" class == 'collapse'    "> + </span>
```

Is there a simple way to get the class of an element on Angular2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually in Angular2 the setup should be the other way around, the model is updated and the view reflects the model. This way you don't need to access the DOM to check it's state. However if you must this should do:

```
<span #span *ngIf="hasClass(span.className, 'collapse') && hasClass(span.className, 'in')"> - </span>
<span #span *ngIf="hasClass(span.className, 'collapse')"> + </span>
```

```
hasClass(classes, cls) {
    return (' ' + classes + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/className

or

```
<span #span *ngIf="span.classList.contains('collapse') && span.classList.contains('in')"> - </span>
<span #span *ngIf="span.classList.contains('collapse')"> + </span>
```

Comment: Is there a typo in hasClass(classes,cls) function? Should the 'className' be 'classes'?

Comment: I think it should work with `className`. You can also use `classList.contains()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList. This is short enough to be used inline without a method in the component, but there are some cases where this is not supported yet (IE and SVG elements for example AFAIR)

Comment: I meant that it should be 
    return (' ' + **classes** + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
It worked this way.

Comment: Something probably changed about the context that you can access a template ref from. I had create a child div that was able to access span. <span #span>
  <div *ngIf="span.classList.contains('collapse')"">

  </div>
</span>